# How to enable CP Subsystem when using Hazelcast Helm

Tags: hazelcast, kubernetes-helm

I am using stable/hazelcast Helm to deploy my Hazelcast instance.

I am not sure how to enable CP Subsystem using the values.yaml and how to set the number of CP MemberCount for this instance.

Using: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/hazelcast

Answer (score 1):

Is this any help, https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/test/resources/hazelcast-fullconfig-without-network.yaml#L815 ?

Add the `hazelcast.cp-subsystem` in a configuration file might be the simplest way

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned by Neil, change your Hazelcast configuration, you can do it in your `values.yaml`: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/hazelcast/values.yaml#L34

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found out how. You have to create a config map which you then reference in your hazelcast manifest file, then you can use the normal `yaml` configurations to configure hazelcast

Example:

1. Create a config map called `my-hazelcast-cluster-config` and then using the hazelcast yaml configuration, configure your CP subsystem settings.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-hazelcast-cluster-config
data:
  hazelcast: |-
    cluster-name: dev
    cp-subsystem:
      cp-member-count: 7
      group-size: 7
```

2. Reference the above config map in your hazelcast cluster manifest:

```
apiVersion: hazelcast.com/v1alpha1
kind: Hazelcast
metadata:
  name: my-hazelcast-cluster
spec:
  clusterSize: 3
  clusterName: dev
  repository: 'docker.io/hazelcast/hazelcast'
  version: '5.3.2-slim'
  customConfigCmName: my-hazelcast-cluster-config
```

Reference:
Hazelcast [docs](https://docs.hazelcast.com/operator/5.9/custom-config)